# how can I get Windows Remote Desktop to work on two monitors instead of just one?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, remote-desktop, remote-access

At home, I have two monitors on my computer running Vista, which I then use Windows Remote Desktop to access a remote Windows computer.  But, the Remote Desktop session only uses just one of my home monitors.

I want to have it use both monitors, to have all the screen for the remote session.

Complication:  I keep one of my home monitors veritical, which is great for source code.

Comment: -1 for not being a programming question

Comment: SuperUser or ServerFault might be better places for questions like these. That being said: `mstsc /span` with current RDP-Client does the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you need a version of Remote Desktop Client 7.0 to achieve this. This is the version that came with Windows 7 but you can download an update here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084

Once you have the latest version of the RDC client here's instructions on setting up multiple monitors: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx)

Comment: +1 didn't knew /multimon, nice :)

Comment: Do you have a solution for windows 10?

Comment: @LuisGouveia you're probably better off asking a new question specifically about windows 10. I can't help you, I migrated to linux as of win 8.